# How to add legend() on plot() in R programming

Tags: r, plot, legend

I run these code：

```
library("quantmod")
symbols = c('^VLIC', 'GE', 'KO', 'AAPL', 'MCD')
getSymbols(symbols, src='yahoo', from="2012-02-01", to="2013-02-01")

#obtain adjusted closed
VLICad = VLIC$VLIC.Adjusted
GEad = GE$GE.Adjusted
KOad = KO$KO.Adjusted
AAPLad = AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted
MCDad = MCD$MCD.Adjusted

#compute cumulative sum (cumsum) of daily returns (Delt)
#Remove first term of the series, with [-1,], since cumsum is not defined for it.

vl = cumsum((Delt(VLICad)*100)[-1,])
ge = cumsum((Delt(GEad)*100)[-1,])
ko = cumsum((Delt(KOad)*100)[-1,])
ap = cumsum((Delt(AAPLad)*100)[-1,])
md = cumsum((Delt(MCDad)*100)[-1,])

###range of values for the plot
lim = c(min(vl, ge, ko, ap, md), max(vl, ge, ko, ap, md))
plot(vl, main="", ylim=lim, xlab="dates", ylab="% benefits")
lines(ge, col="green")
lines(ko, col="red")
lines(ap, col="violet")
lines(md, col="yellow")

legend(x = "topleft", 
       cex = 0.4,c("VLIC", "GE", "KO", "AAPL", "MCD"), 
       lty = "l", 
       col = c("black", "green", "red", "violet", "yellow"), 
       text.col = c("black", "green", "red", "violet", "yellow"))
```

I can produce the result like this:

[image: Result Image]

But i cannot get the legend, that means the last line code does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `vl` has class `xts`, when you call the generic function `plot`, the method `plot.xts` is dispatched.  `legend` doesn't play very nicely with xts plots, but `xts::addLegend` does.  Try this:

```
colvec <- c("black","green","red","violet","yellow")
xts::addLegend(legend.loc="topleft", legend.names=c("VLIC","GE","KO","AAPL","MCD"), 
               lty = 1, col=colvec, text.col=colvec, bg="white", bty=1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan Y ! It does works!!! BTW, where can I search the deep detail info ? when I run ?legend()  , just show me how to use the legend() method.

Comment: I think Hadley's chapter ([link](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html)) on S3 methods does a good job introducing generics and methods.  Otherwise, you just need to know to be on the lookout, and the usual suspects are `plot`, `summary`, and `print`.  For your specific case, I noticed that your plot didn't look like a Base R plot (it had a lot of customization), so I ran `class(vl)` to see that the first argument to your plot command had classes `xts` and `zoo`.  Then I did `?plot.xts` to start to dig in.